# Discord.js bot isn't clearing messages, but still sends the x amount of messages have been deleted message

Tags: discord.js

I tried to copy this piece of code over from a previous bot I have made on the same server with a different command name, and now it isn't deleting the messages and I can't figure out why not.

```
bot.on('message', msg =>{
  if(!msg.author.bot && msg.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
  {
    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0])

    {
      case 'ClearMessages':
        if (msg.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["RNGesus"].includes(r.name)))
        {
          msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1], true).catch(err=> {
            console.error(err)
            msg.channel.send("An error has occured while trying to delete messages")
          });
          msg.channel.send(`${args[1]} messages have been deleted`)
          .then(msg =>{
            msg.delete({timeout: 3000})
          })
          .catch(console.error)
        }
      break;
```

It also doesn't give any error messages in the console when the bot is supposed to be deleting the messages. If anybody can help at all it would be appreciated, I am fairly new to discord.js and one of my friends helped me make this. I tried to ask them for help but they couldn't figure it out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) is supposed to be an array/collection of messages or number of messages to delete. Obviously you're trying to give a number of messages to delete, however you're actually providing a *string*.

You need to first convert `args[0]` to a number using the [unary plus operator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), then round it to an integer using [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (or using a double [bitwise NOT operator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) if you want to be fancy and more efficient). As a suggestion, you should also put in a check to make sure the number is valid.

```js
if (msg.member.roles.cache.some((r) => ['RNGesus'].includes(r.name))) {
 if (+args[1] < 2 || +args[1] > 100)
  return message.channel.send('The number must be at least 2 and at most 100');
 msg.channel.bulkDelete(Math.floor(+args[1]), true).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  msg.channel.send('An error has occured while trying to delete messages');
 });
 msg.channel
  .send(`${args[1]} messages have been deleted`)
  .then((msg) => {
   msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
}
```